# NextJS fetch data for dynamic route

Tags: javascript, next.js

This is my route:

```
post/[id].tsx
```

And this my code:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [{ params: { 'id': '200'} }],
        fallback: true
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.com/${params.id}`)
    const post = await res.json()
    return { props: { post } }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

1- How can I pass my custom params to `paths`?

2- After run the code, my page rendered twice

I don't want get all ids in `getStaticPaths`

Comment: What is "my custom"? The page renders twice, but that's not an issue since that only happens at build time.

Comment: @evolutionxbox "my custom params". So, is it ok for twice render ?!

Comment: Since `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` only run at build time, I think it's fine.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you. How can I pass router.query to getStaticPaths ?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. [The docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes/dynamic-routes-details) say _"If you want to access the Next.js router, you can do so by importing the `useRouter` hook from `next/router`."_

Comment: You can't access query params in `getStaticPaths`. Keep in mind `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` run at build time on the server to pre-generate the pages, they have no access to request-specific data like query params.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're trying to achieve though - why do you want query params in `getStaticPaths`?

Comment: @juliomalves I want fetch data from API. but I have to get all /users/ data from api in getStaticPaths. My users table is huge and I can't get all users first time. so I want to get only one ID and pass it to API.

Comment: What you currently have should work as you intend, having `fallback: true` ensures new pages for `id`s not generated in `getStaticPaths` will be created when requested. Alternatively, you can use `fallback: 'blocking'` if you'd rather wait for the new pages to be generated before rendering them, preventing the double rendering you mentioned.

Comment: @juliomalves `return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: 'blocking'
    };` work for me. thank you